# Properties of set-maps that commute

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Suppose $f, g$ are set-maps from some set $S$ to itself such that $f \circ g = g \circ f$. (1) What can we say about $f, g$? There seems to be surprisingly little.

If not, consider the following specialization: $f$ is a set-map from $S$ to itself such that for *all* maps $g$ (also from $S$ to itself) we have $f \circ g = g \circ f$. (2) Can we now say anything about $f$?

If still not, consider the following generalization (?): $f, g$ are set-maps from $S$ to itself, $T$ to itself respectively, such that for all maps $\varphi: S \rightarrow T$, we have $\varphi \circ f = g \circ \varphi$. (3) What can we now say about $f, g$?

(The original problem, made most obvious by (3), is to find all natural transformations of the identity functor $Set \rightarrow Set$. These questions are just what I found to be the obvious things to think about. Unfortunately, I'm having a hard time answering any of them and would appreciate some help.)

Comment: "There seems to be surprisingly little" - on the contrary, think for example of commuting matrices $AB=BA$, where there are so many results.

Comment: I guess this is true, but nothing seems to really carry over to sets. Where there is no structure (i.e. when the objects are simply sets), it feels like I can say nothing about the relationships $f$ and $g$ must have.

Comment: For the specialization, $f$ must be the identity. If $f(x)\neq x$, then if $g$ is constant at $x$, we have $f(g(x))=f(x)\neq x=g(f(x))$.

Comment: I don't follow; is your last equality that $g(f(x)) = x$? Or are you just saying that $g(f(x)) = f(g(x))$ can't be $x$, so this is a contradiction? Neither of these seems true...

Comment: Now posted to, and closed on, MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/348792/commuting-dynamical-systems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this: if $f(x)=x$ then $f(g(x))=g(f(x))=g(x)$. To put it in words, $g$ maps each fixed point of $f$ to a fixed point of $f$.

And then another thought: since $f^2 \circ g = f \circ g \circ f = g \circ f^2$, it follows that $g$ maps each fixed point of $f^2$ to a fixed point of $f^2$. And to translate that into a statement about $f$ itself, $g$ maps each point of period at most $2$ for $f$ to a point of period at most $2$ for $f$.

And then a further thought: by a similar argument for each natural number $n$, $g$ maps each point of period at most $n$ for $f$ to a point of period at most $n$ for $f$.

And then, by symmetry, $f$ maps each point of period at most $n$ for $g$ to a point of period at most $n$ for $g$.

Perhaps there's even more...

Comment: Thanks for the response, Lee. I've tried playing with your idea a bit, and I think it's helped me at least articulate the core of problem (1) a little better: it feels like for any given $f, g$ it isn't too hard to list necessary properties using e.g. your answer, but it is hard to say anything further for general $f, g$. That being said, in the context of my second and third problem, it's clear that there are maps with no fixed points at all, so obviously $f$ can't exist!